# Kernel Panic after interrupting installation of Proxmox 7.3

Tags: linux, proxmox, kernel-panic

I tried to install **Proxmox 7.3** on my newly built homeserver.
The **install hanged** for 10 minutes at the first step which was wiping the ssd, **so I rebooted the system**, thinking it was frozen indefinitely.

Now I **cannot boot into ANY linux distro** from USB, because a kernel panic happens almost instantly.

I tried the proxmox USB and an arch linux USB, which both work fine on my other machine.

The server is selfbuilt and has the following specs:

| Part | Model |
| --- | --- |
| CPU | AMD Ryzen 9 7950X |
| RAM | 4x 32GB DDR5 Kingston FURY |
| Mainboard | AsRock X670E Pro RS |
| SSD | WD Red SN700 500GB M.2 |
| HDD | 6x WD Red Plus 4TB |
| Power Supply | LC Power LC550 V2.31 550W |

I ran memtest86+ v6.00 (shipped with proxmox) on my ram, finding 2000+ errors.
Then I ran memtest64+ v10.2 which found NO Errors?!

How do I diagnose this correctly?

Thanks for any support :(

**EVENT LOG:**

| ID | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | Removing all ram sticks but one allowed me to boot. I am now testing the sticks individually. |
| 02 | Memtest86+ v6.00 froze during the first test mentioned above. The second try froze after test #2 featuring 864 errors. **I will now test a different RAM module |
| 03 | The remaining modules all failed at step #2, Memtest86+ v6.00 crashed directly after the first errors displayed. |
| 04 | Interrupted maintenance for ~1h |
| 05 | Rollback to last stable UEFI version. I was on the latest BETA version => Memtest with one Ram stick successful, Memtest with two RAM sticks successful as well, now testing with 4 sticks |

Comment: I suppose there are other options for what is causing the problems as well, but what memory is this exactly and what settings are used? With/without EXPO or XMP applied? Latest UEFI version?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist The RAM runs at stock settings. Is this information enough? RAM: 64GB Kingston FURY Beast DDR5-4800 DIMM CL 38 Dual Kit. BUT!!!! I was running the UEFI Beta release from the manufacturer. I just flashed the newest stable release and the errors seem to have vanished. At least it works with one ram stick. I will increase to 2 then to 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue myself.

The solution was to ROLL BACK to a STABLE UEFI release. I was using the latest BETA which had some issues apparently.

Now all seems to be working and Proxmox was successfully installed. :-)

Comment: please accept your own answer for question to be marked as solved

Comment: New users cannot resolved before days. Resolved now 